# Updating dynamic gridpane in javafx. Once it's drawn, it doesn't update again with the updated parameters (row,column)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am trying to design bus seat structure in javafx application using sceneBuilder. Where `drawBus` is a `GridPane` which is under an `AnchorPane`(Bus Structure Anchorpane). This anchorpane is drawn using scenebuilder. and DrawBus `GridPane` is drawn in the controller class using code. When `Loadinfo` Button is pressed it draws bus seat structure.

```
@FXML
private void Loadinfo(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, ParseException {

   String co=(String) coachBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
   
   getbusinfo(getBusID(co));
   
   coachLbl.setText(co);
   SubRouteLbl.setText(source+"-"+destination);
   BusNameLbl.setText(busname);
   
   
  
  
  
  //Adding Gridpane to the anchorpane of Bus Seat structure
  int row=Integer.parseInt(totalrows);
  int col=Integer.parseInt(totalcolumns);
  System.out.println("row: "+row);
  System.out.println("col: "+col);
  
  
  
  BusStructure.getChildren().add(drawBus(row,col)); 
  AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(drawBus(row,col),0.0);
  AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(drawBus(row,col),0.0);
  AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(drawBus(row,col),0.0);
  AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(drawBus(row,col),0.0);
  
      

}
```

Here is my code where drawBus is called. `totalrows` & `totalcolumns` are data taken from json file.

```
public static String totalcolumns;  
public static String totalrows;

public static GridPane drawBus(int rows, int col){
    GridPane table = new GridPane();

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        
        for(int j=0;j<col; j++)
        {
        Button seat=new Button();
        seat.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        seat.setPrefSize(80, 31);
        seat.setText(i+","+j);
        seat.setStyle("-fx-background-color: MediumSeaGreen");

        //add them to the GridPane
        table.add(seat, j, i); //  (child, columnIndex, rowIndex)


        // margins 
        GridPane.setMargin(seat, new Insets(2));
        GridPane.setMargin(seat, new Insets(2));
        GridPane.setMargin(seat, new Insets(2));
     }
    table.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    
    }
    return table;
}
```

Each time `coachNumber` changes from the choice box The BusInfo is updated and `totalrows` and `totalcolumns` changes. To check the changes I have printed the values in `Loadinfo` function. The row and col changes properly. But the `BusStructure`(Gridpane) remains as it is updated first time Load Info Button is clicked.

For more detail I am attaching my UI image.

#### first image when bus seat structure is drawn first time

[image: first image when bus seat structure is drawn first time]

#### second image where coach number changes from choicebox but bus structure remains same

[image: second image where coach number changes from choicebox but bus structure remains same]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never remove old `GridPane`s from the `AnchorPane`. This means you overlay all the results of the `drawBus` method. Probably the first bus you load is the biggest one and the scene looks the same after adding smaller buses on top of it.

To fix this issue replace `GridPane`.

Furthermore you create new `GridPane`s when setting the anchors. This has no effect on the `GridPane` added to the scene. Also setting the margin 3 times for the same seat does not provide benefits. To assign different values to different sides use the `Insets` constructor taking 4 parameters. You could also use `hgap` and `vgap` (adding a padding to the `GridPane` if needed) to set the horizontal/vertical distance of children for the `GridPane`:

```
public static GridPane drawBus(int rows, int col){
    GridPane table = new GridPane();
    table.setHgap(4);
    table.setVgap(4);
    table.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){

        for(int j=0;j<col; j++) {
            Button seat=new Button();
            seat.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            seat.setPrefSize(80, 31);
            seat.setText(i+","+j);
            seat.setStyle("-fx-background-color: MediumSeaGreen");

            //add them to the GridPane
            table.add(seat, j, i); //  (child, columnIndex, rowIndex)
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

```
private GridPane currentTable;

@FXML
private void Loadinfo(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, ParseException {

    String co=(String) coachBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    getbusinfo(getBusID(co));

    coachLbl.setText(co);
    SubRouteLbl.setText(source+"-"+destination);
    BusNameLbl.setText(busname);

    //Adding Gridpane to the anchorpane of Bus Seat structure
    int row=Integer.parseInt(totalrows);
    int col=Integer.parseInt(totalcolumns);
    System.out.println("row: "+row);
    System.out.println("col: "+col);

    GridPane newTable = drawBus(row,col);

    if (currentTable == null) {
        BusStructure.getChildren().add(newTable);
    } else {
        // replace table
        BusStructure.getChildren().set(BusStructure.getChildren().indexOf(currentTable), newTable);
    }

    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(newTable, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(newTable, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(newTable, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(newTable, 0.0);

    // save reference to table to determine which node to replace
    currentTable = newTable;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I was unable to find out the problem because I loaded bigger grid first. Then when I changed smaller to bigger grid i could see the changes and realized my mistake. Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!BusStructure.getChildren().isEmpty())
  {
      BusStructure.getChildren().remove(0);
  }
  BusStructure.getChildren().add(drawBus(row,col)); 
  AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(drawBus(row,col),0.0);
  AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(drawBus(row,col),0.0);
  AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(drawBus(row,col),0.0);
  AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(drawBus(row,col),0.0);
```

adding this if condition solved my problem.